# "Hit the ground running" - other short ways to say it?

Tags: synonyms, idiom-requests

I have found the perfect expression but I can't use it!

Is there **any other way** to say the same thing as:

> hit the ground running?

I need to describe a tool that helps you **learn stuff super fast**, think **Matrix** and kung fu, when neo loads kung fu skill to his brain instantly

Comment: Percuss the soil while locomoting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of a closed question, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/438522/what-are-good-alternatives-to-hit-the-ground-running

Comment: Hard to know if the key request here is "skill into his brain instantly" and whether it was really "sense of full-on practical experience" in the other rather than "hit the ground running" which was in the title of both and perhaps slightly off for both. @Xanne

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few idiomatic phrases that imply a quick start to a continued action in slightly different ways.

**Jump-start** ( this is about starting a car and perhaps more about "re-starting" so perhaps not perfect)

**Leap into** ( perhaps implies getting into an action already in a dynamic state)

**Dive in** ( perhaps more about 'immersion' and sink or swim than forward momentum, although "**diving start**" might be hit another)

"**bootstrap**" is a different concept of 'self starting'  'picking oneself up by one's own bootstaps" was the old idiom which turned into a computing term which was a sort of start up protocol where the initial steps loaded additional functions which in turn could be used to get a full suite of functions for an operating system going.

Comment: From Merriam-Webster, one meaning of *jump-start* is "to start or restart (something) rapidly or forcefully ·  advertising can *jump-start* a political campaign." So, it's appropriate. A close synonym is *kick-start*.

Answer (score 0):

**be raring to go**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+raring+to+go)

> To be eager and ready to take action.

Answer (score 0):

A tool that gives you a [crash course](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crash%20course) in [whatever]:

> a rapid and intense course of study; *also* : an experience that
>   resembles such a course · has been given a *crash course* in diplomacy
>   in his first weeks in office